# My board doesn't boot from the s.d card

Tags: u-boot

I put the SD card in the sd slot and tried to boot by pressing the S2 button while I connect the board to the usb for power the four led's began to flash but the image won't display on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you do not supply any hint to which brand of board you are trying to boot.

You should gather the output of the serial console to learn what is happening.